# GGPLOT2 how can i get a label on every log10 step?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

Im trying to create a plot with a log10 y-scale. it does scale it correctly, but i cant get it to label every line. At the moment i only get 10^4, 10^6 and 10^8. how can i get the 10^3 and 10^5?

```
scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',
                 labels = dollar,
                 limits = c(1000,NA),
                 breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(y) 10^y),
                 #minor_breaks = 0,
                 )
```

[image: log10 y-scale]

Comment: Adjust `n` in the `trans_break` call.

Comment: @caldwellst well, thats amazing. thanks a lot